# Oracle SQL | How to add text at a couple different positions for every row in a certain field

Tags: sql, oracle

So if I had the following numbers in a table...

```
ID 
9102342
4239102
4348327
```

... and I wanted to change the format of them to look like this...

```
ID
91-0234-2
42-3910-2
43-4832-7
```

...how would I go about changing them to the new format?

Comment: Always 7 digit numbers? Cast as char and do some substring and concat.

Comment: looks like homework...

Comment: Not homework; working on a project for my employer and I ran into an issue with IDs not being the same format between tables. Although I can see where you got it from.

Answer (score 3):

```
select substr(id, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(id, 3, 4) || '-' || substr(id, 7)
from some_table
```

[SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions195.htm) documentation.

**EDIT**

```
substr(id, 1, 2)
```

The 2nd parameter with value `1` means to start reading the string at position `1`.

The 3rd parameter with value `2` means to read 2 characters from the position specified in the previous parameter.  If you don't specify this parameter, then it means that it should read all remaining characters.

If you have a value like `89234222013`, and you want to get `89234-22-2013`, then you would do the following:

```
select substr(id, 1, 5) || '-' || substr(id, 6, 2) || '-' || substr(id, 8)
from some_table
```

**EDIT 2**

And of course, if you wish to use an `UPDATE` statement, then just do this:

```
update some_table
set id = substr(id, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(id, 3, 4) || '-' || substr(id, 7);
```

Comment: What do the two numbers in each substr represent? What if the number was 11 characters (like 89234222013) and I wanted it to have dashes after the fifth number and after the seventh (like 89234-22-2013?)

Comment: I edited my answer.  But really, you should just have a look at the documentation I linked.  It's pretty clearly explained.

Comment: Downvote?  A little helpful explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edits; I missed the SUBSTR link completely.

Comment: sorry dv was me thinking i undid the an upvote. returning the vote back.

Answer (score 1):

You can update with substring and create different handler for different lengths

```
UPDATE table SET field = CASE LENGTH(field)
    WHEN 7 THEN substr(field, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(field 3, 4) || '-' || substr(field, 7)
    WHEN 6 THEN (ANOTHER HANDLER FOR STRING WITH 6 CHAR )

END CASE;
```

You can add as many Cases as you want and replace them correctly in one query

Comment: technically this is the correct answer, OP asked to change the ID to the new format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, using `regexp_replace()` regular expressions function(Oracle 10g and up).

```
with t1(num) as(
  select 9102342 from dual union all
  select 4239102 from dual union all
  select 4348327 from dual union all
  select 1234567894565 from dual
)
select regexp_replace(to_char(num)
                     , '(([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4}))'
                     , '\2-\3-') as res
  from t1
```

Result:

```
RES                          
------------------------------
91-0234-2                      
42-3910-2                      
43-4832-7                      
12-3456-78-9456-5
```